# How to prove an inequality for a C1 function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f$ be a function in  $C^1(0,T)$ satisfying  $f'(t)\ge cf(t)^3-d$, where $c,d$ are two strictly positive constants.

I would like to prove that if  $f(0)\ge(2d/c)^{1/3}$ then $f(t)\ge(2d/c)^{1/3}$ for all $t$ in $(0,T) $
Can someone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you sure you did not assume $f(0)> (2d/c)^{1/3}$ ?

Comment: ah yes your true i have $f(0)> (2d/c)^{1/3}$

Comment: Fnacool ,can you please help me to prove that?

Answer (score 1):

Enough to check what happens if

$f(0)=(2d/c)^{1/3}$. Then $f'(0)=d$, so $f$ is increasing near $0$.

We continue by contradiction.

Suppose that there exists some $t\le T$ such that $f(t) \le  f(0)$.

Choose the **minimal** such $t$.

We must  have then $f(t)=f(0)$, by continuity. Note that $t>0$ because $f$ is increasing near $0$.

By the mean value theorem, there exists $t_1 \in (0,t)$ (important: strictly between $0$ and $t$), such that $f'(t_1)=0$.

But this means:

$$ 0 = f'(t_0) \ge  c f^3(t_0) -d,$$

As a result, $f(t_0) \le (d/c)^{1/3}<f(0)$. This contradicts the minimality of $t$.

Comment: the only thing that i didn't understand is why we have f(s)=f(0)?

Comment: simplifies the proof, omitted $s$. This is because the continuity of $f$. If it ever goes below a value, it must cross it...

Answer (score 0):

If the condition is safisfied, then $f'(0)>0$. Assume $t_0>0$ is the smallest time for which $f(t)\leq 2\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1/3}$. Show the following:

1. There exist $t_1<t_0$ such that $f'(t_1)<0$
2. $f(t_1)\leq 2\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1/3}$, which contradicts the minimality of $t_0$.

Edit: I add the follwing step:

1. If the assumption holds, then $f'(0)>0$. Therefore, there is $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f(t)>2\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1/3}$ in $(0,\varepsilon)$.

If you can show this, then calling $a$ a point in $(0,\varepsilon)$ such that $f(a)>2\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1/3}$, which clearly satisfies $a<t_0$, you can use the Lagrange (Mean Value) theorem to show the existence of $t_1$.

By the way, your problem is equivalent to the following: if $g'(t)\geq g^3(t)$ in $(0,T)$ and $g(0)\geq0$, then $g(t)\geq 0$ in $(0,T)$. Not that it changes much, but at least you would not need to carry all those constants around...

Comment: the second point is easy to show: if $f'(t_1)<0$ than $cf(t_1)-d<0$ then $f(t_1)\leq 2\left(\frac{d}{c}\right)^{1/3}$ but i don't no how to prove the first point can you help me?